# regexp for (domain.zzz domain.zz.zz domain.zz) and /something/

Tags: python, regex

Trying to get domain.zz or domain.zzz or domain.zz.zz or /something.

```
import re
the_string = """lalalla?url=http2F%2Fdomain.zz%slgkfgs0s"""
the_string = """lalalla?url=http2F%2Fdomain.zz.zz/something%slgkfgs0sf"""
the_string = """lalalla?url=randomh564domain.zzz/something%slgkfgs0sf"""
the_string = """lalalla?url=randomeefsdlk876%domain.zz/something%slgkfgs0sf"""
the_string = """p%3A%2F%2Fdummy_test.com/ratata%2F&amp"""
the_string = """p%3A%2F%2Fdum2test.co.uk/something%2F&-kj"""
```

This is what i have now:

```
>>> print( re.findall('(?:www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4})(?:/[a-z0-9]+)',the_string))
domain.zzz/something
domain.zz/something
domain.zz.zz/something

>>> print( re.findall('www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}',the_string))
domain.zzz
domain.zz
domain.zz.zz
```

And i would like to get those two groups with one re question.

EDIT:
This one is almost perfect:
'([a-z0-9.-]+[.][a-z]{2,4})|(?:/[a-z0-9]+)'
but it grabs some trash from the beginning of the string.

The string is much more random than in this example: 
I am focusing on those 3 cases:

```
domain.co.uk/something
      ^  ^  ^
domain.com/something
      ^   ^
domain.com
      ^
```

Comment: No, it's not.  It changes.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
import re
the_string = """lalalla?url=http@domain.zz%slgkfgs0sf"""
the_string = """lalalla?url=http@domain.zz.zz/something%slgkfgs0sf"""
#the_string = """lalalla?url=http@domain.zzz/something%slgkfgs0sf"""
#the_string = """lalalla?url=ht%domain.zz/something%slgkfgs0sf"""
#the_string = """lalalla?url=httpsd%domain.zz.zz/something%slgkfgs0sf"""
#the_string = """lalalla?url=www.domain.zzz/something%slgkfgs0sf"""

test = re.compile('(?P<base>[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*?[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.[z\.]+)(?P<extra>/[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)')

for match in test.finditer(the_string):
    print(match.group('base'))
    print(match.group('extra'))
```

ouput:

```
domain.zz.zz
/something
```

This way you'll have both data in 'base' and 'extra'...combine them to get the full string again.

edit: updated the pattern for better domain matching and changed prints for python 3 syntax

Comment: I just noticed the '\w' isn't enough to match domain names with '-', so I can rewrite that if you want.

Comment: I pasted the complete script now, what is not working for you?

Comment: The regex question shows 0 results, (im on python3.3 right now). - and it's not about the print. Checked again to be sure and None found.

Comment: Just read this: print() is a function in Python 3 (it was a statement in Python 2), so you have to call it. Try print(match.group('base'))

Comment: Thank you for help, but it still doesn't work. It can't find <base>, i will edit and check.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I don't know if this exactly matches zyour requirements but maybe you could clarify the problems, pattern a little further if there are problems...

```
print re.findall('=(?:[^@%/.]*(?:@|%(?:2F)?))?(?:www.)?(?P<domain>[^%@/]*)(?:/(?P<folder>[^%]*))?(?:[%@/].*)?$',the_string,re.MULTILINE)
```

If you wish you can access the parts with `match.group('domain')` and `match.group('folder')`

Output:

```
[('domain.zz', ''), ('domain.zz.zz', 'something'), ('randomh564domain.zzz', 'something'), ('domain.zz', 'something'), ('domain.zz.zz', 'something'), ('domain.zzz', 'something')]
```

Comment: @okobaka what do you mean?  The `(?P<domain>...)` just creates a named subgroup. Look for `(?P<name>...)` [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax). Maybe give an example how/why it won't work.

Comment: I think it is related to encoding.  check this string: "p%3A%2F%2Fdummy_test.com/ratata%2F&amp"

Comment: what would you like to get for that as a result? why don't you simply decode the string before you match?